# I am not able start my wlan service, how to fix this?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I am trying to start my `wlan` service for make a hotspot in my system. But I am getting an error as : to start I am using this command (`NETSH WLAN start hostednetwork`)

```
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

But when i see the status of the `wlan` I am getting the info like this:

[image: Status of my wlan cofig]

What do I require to do to fix the issue?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182084/cant-start-hostednetwork) answer might be helpful.

Comment: as like the answered, I am not able to see `Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter` in my adopter list.